# how to sort an integer that is declared in the private

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting

I declared the int id in the private, part of my class.

```
                    private:
                      int id,age;
                      float gpa;
                      string last,first;
```

This code is in my file to display and call for functions that are in the array, and to sort the int id.

```
        student[i].sort_array(student[i].id,cap);
        i++;
        cout << i;
```

This is in a seperate file where i put my functions, i am able to display the contents of the array, if i student[i].put(cout) the data. I am not sure how to pass in an integer that would be in the provate part of my class

```
        void student::sort_array(int student[i].get(id),int n)
        {

            int j,temp;
            for(j=0;j<n-1;j++)
            { 
         //if out of position switch the out of align number
            if(student[j]<student[j+1])
            {
            temp =  student[j];
            student[j] = student[j+1];
            student[j+1] = temp;
            }
         }
```

Comment: `void student::sort_array(int student[i].get(id),int n)` doesn't make any sense.

Comment: `.sort_array` shouldn't be a member of one specific student.

Comment: How comfortable are you with C++? Is this homework?

Comment: I am trying to teach myself programming, by making a program for school.

Answer (score 3):

The normal method is to have a `bool student::compareAges(Student const& otherStudent)` method, aand pass that as an extra argument to your comparison function. E.g. it's the third argument to `std::sort` when you're not using the default `operator<`

Comment: Indeed, although to fit the question I'd say it should be `student::compareIDs`. The point being that you teach `Student` how to compare itself to another `Student` so your sorting code doesn't have to know about any internal details.

Answer (score 0):

The sort_array function must not be in a different file but in the .cpp of your Student class decleration.

And you do not have to pass the id as a parameter since you can access (even if it is private) it because you will be in that class's scope.

Answer (score 0):

`sort_array` doesn't belong in the `student` `class`! Nor does it make sense "to sort the int id" for an instance of `student`.

Sorting a collection of `student`s *by* `id` using the C++ standard library's [**`std::sort()`**](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) function is certainly possible.

You can define a *less-than* `operator` for your `student` class, thus:

```
bool student::operator <(student const& rhs) const
{
    return id < rhs.id;
}
```

Since it is a member of the `class` it can access all of its data.

It must be `public:`, then `std::sort()` function will be able to use this to sort a standard C++ container (or array) of `student`. based on the `id`. If you want to compare multiple attributes of the `class`, be sure to implement [strict weak ordering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/979759/operator-and-strict-weak-ordering).