# C++ map not behaving properly

Tags: c++, data-structures, stl, dictionary

I have defined my class *SumClass* and trying to use it in a map as shown in the code below. I have defined the required *<, =* and *==* operator.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <map>

using namespace std;

class SumClass {
    public:
    int id;
    int sum;
    SumClass() { id = sum = 0;}
    bool operator<(const SumClass& rhs) const{
        if( (id < rhs.id) && (sum< rhs.sum)) return true;
        else return false;
    }
    bool operator==(const SumClass& rhs) const{
        //if(this == &rhs) return true;
        if( (id == rhs.id) && (sum == rhs.sum) ) return true;
        else return false;
    }
    void set(int idd, int summ) { id = idd; sum = summ; }
    SumClass& operator=(const SumClass& rhs){
        id = rhs.id;
        sum = rhs.sum;
        return *this;
    }
};

void test(){
    map<SumClass, int> m;
    SumClass temp;
    temp.set(0,3);
    m[temp] = -1;
    temp.set(-1, 3);
    m[temp] = -1;
    temp.set(-1, 2);
    m[temp] = -1;
    temp.set(0, 1);
    cout << "Test: " << m[temp] << endl;
}


int main(){
    test();
}
```

The output of the code above is: "Test: -1". But the expected output is "Test: 0" as the SumClass element I am trying to find is not present in the map. Can anyone please point what am I doing wrong ?

Comment: You shouldn't need `operator==`. Equality is checked in there using `operator<`.

Comment: @chris. I guess it will figure out "a == b" if both 'a < b' and 'b < a' returns false. Isn't it ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `operator<` does not provide a [strict weak ordering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strict_weak_ordering).

Try this:

```
bool operator<(const SumClass& rhs) const{
  return std::tie(id, sum) < std::tie(rhs.id, rhs.sum);
}
```

Or, if you cannot use C++11 features:

```
bool operator<(const SumClass& rhs) const{
  return std::make_pair(id, sum) < std::make_pair(rhs.id, rhs.sum);
}
```

Comment: It's fine for a strict weak ordering to have distinct incomparable values; the relevant requirement is that incomparability model an equivalence relation.

Comment: @ecatmur - Thanks! I've deleted the part where I obviously didn't know what I was talking about.

Comment: Thanks Rob, I compiled the code with make_pair and it worked fine. However I couldn't compile the code with std:tie even when I used the c++0x compiler of g++

Comment: This answer is very useful, but it is not the complete solution for the problem.

Answer (score 2):

You haven't defined the required operators; your `operator<` is not a strict weak ordering.

For example, `(0, 0) < (1, 1)`, but neither `(0, 0) < (0, 1)` nor `(0, 1) < (1, 1)` holds, violating transitivity of equivalence.

See [Operator< and strict weak ordering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/979759/operator-and-strict-weak-ordering) for how to write a strict weak ordering.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect this is wrong:

```
 bool operator<(const SumClass& rhs) const{
        if( (id < rhs.id) && (sum< rhs.sum)) return true;
        else return false;
    }
```

Are they really both **always** going to have this relation?

Comment: Thanks John, my understanding of strict weak ordering wasn't clear.

Answer (score 0):

`map::operator[]` is trying to find the value in the map. If it finds it, it returns a reference to it. If it does not find it, then it creates it. You might consider using `map::find`.

Comment: I don't understand why would it create it and even if it does, what would it do with the value ?

Comment: The value will be created with a standard ctor. In your case it seems to be 0 :-). It's defined this way in the C++ standard. The idea behind it is that you can insert values with 'map[key] = value', which BTW you are using in your code. The insertion into the map is done during `map[key]`, not during the `operator =`.