# How to change pair (> and <) operators behavior?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, std-pair

I'm trying to sort a `vector< pair<int,char> >` but i want to change the behavior of the comparison operators of the pair type , so that if the first values equal and it'a comparing with (>) operator, i want it to compare the second value with (<) operator.

I'm trying to do this to solve the "[What's Cryptanalysis](http://uva.onlinejudge.org/index.php?option=onlinejudge&page=show_problem&problem=949)?" problem on uva .
Here is my approach :

```
string toLower(string in){
    string out;
    for(int i=0;i<in.length();i++){
        if(in.at(i)<='Z' && in.at(i)>='A'){
            out+=in.at(i)+('a'-'A');
        }
        else if(in.at(i)<='z' && in.at(i)>='a'){
            out+=in.at(i);
        }
    }
    return out;
}


int main(){
    //freopen("in.txt","r",stdin);
    //freopen("tmp.txt","w",stdout);
    vector< pair<int,char> >vp;
    pair<int,char> tp;

    for(char a='a';a<='z';a++){//buliding a table of values and chars
        tp= make_pair(0,a);
        vp.push_back(tp);
    }
    int T;
    cin >> T;
    string s;
    cin.ignore();
    for(int i=0;i<T;i++){
        getline(cin,s);
        s=toLower(s);//remove special chars and convert all to lower
        int l=s.length();
        for(int j=0;j<l;j++){
            vp[s[j]-'a'].first+=1;//increasing the value of each char found
        }
    }
    sort(vp.begin(),vp.end());//ascending sort
    for(int j=25;j>=0;j--){
        cout << (char)(vp[j].second -('a'-'A')) << " " <<vp[j].first << endl;//cout the Capital char and its value backwards (Descending)
    }
    //system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

But this is how output looks like:

```
S 7
T 6
I 5
E 4
O 3
W 2
U 2
N 2
H 2
A 2
Y 1
Q 1
M 1
C 1
Z 0
X 0
V 0
R 0
P 0
L 0
K 0
J 0
G 0
F 0
D 0
B 0
```

so for example i want `W U N H A` to be `A H N U W`

i have read about overloading in other questions but i don't know to implement it here

Comment: you shouldn't overload an operator here. You should implement a custom comparison function and pass that to `std::find` or simply reverse the vector after sorting..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just provide your own comparison function:

```
bool comp(const std::pair<int, char>& a, const std::pair<int, char>& b)
{
  if (a.first > b.first) {
    return true;
  } else if (a.first == b.first && a.second < b.second) {
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}
```

Then use it when you sort:

```
sort(vp.begin(),vp.end(), comp);
```

Answer (score 6):

This is done by passing in a custom comparer function to `sort`. You can most easily do this with a lambda like this:

```
sort(
    vp.begin(),
    vp.end(),
    [](const pair<int,char>& lhs, const pair<int,char>& rhs) -> bool {
        return lhs.first != rhs.first 
            ? lhs.first < rhs.first 
            : lhs.second < rhs.second;
    }
);
```

This code sorts on ascending `first` and then on ascending `second`, but you can tweak the priority and direction of the two comparisons to sort whichever way you want.

Comment: I think `lhs.first < rhs.first` should be `lhs.first > rhs.first` - the asker wants descending order by first element in the pair.

Comment: @sftrabbit: Wasn't trying to nail down the exact sort; it's pretty easy to see how it can be changed. Added a clarification though, thanks.

Comment: thank you for your answer, i know your code should theoretically run faster because of using the simple if statement ,but i chose @sftrabbit code for being more readable by anyone, Thank you again :) .

Answer (score 2):

> I'm trying to sort a vector< pair > but i want to change the behavior of the comparison

Just define a suitable binary predicate function and pass it as third argument to `std::sort`. Bear in mind that it should implement a [strict weak ordering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/979759/operator-and-strict-weak-ordering):

```
bool foo(const pair<int,char>& lhs, const pair<int,char>& rhs)
{
  // implement logic here
}

....

sort(vp.begin(),vp.end(), foo);
```