# how is cmp defined in c++? with < or with <=?

Tags: c++, sorting, stl, compare

I asked me how the cmp function in std::sort and std::is_sorted is defined.

here are two documentations for is_sorted_until how say it should be operator< :

[en.cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/is_sorted_until)
[cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/is_sorted_until/)

But i think there should be a problem with equal elements.
The list {1,1,1} should not be sorted because 1<1==false.
But there is an example which says:

```
...
int *sorted_end = std::is_sorted_until(nums, nums + N);
...
```

1 1 4 9 5 3  : 4 initial sorted elements

but that should return 1 if < is used like documented.

It would work with <=, but that is not the way it is documented.

I'm really confused.

Comment: "but that should return 1 if < is used like documented." no, why should it?

Comment: You might find this question and answers informative in addition to the thousands of results from google: [Operator < and Strict Weak Ordering](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/979759/operator-and-strict-weak-ordering)

Comment: because 1<1==false. so {1,1} is not sorted and {1} would be the largest sorted list.

Comment: A list is considered sorted if `sort(list.begin(), list.end())` would not change it. Sorting `{1,1}` does not change it, ergo it is already sorted.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The comparison is required to define a [strict weak ordering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strict_weak_ordering#Strict_weak_orderings). A strict weak ordering defines a set of equivalence classes from the incomparability relation, i.e., if x < y is false, and y < x is false too (i.e. x and y cannot be compared with <), x and y are considered equivalent. These equivalence classes have a total order, and that's the total order resulting from the sort functions.

In the example given, {1,1,1} has only a single equivalence class, the one composed of {1,1,1}.

`is_sorted_until` finds the first element x[i] for which x[i] < x[i-1] is true.

Answer (score 2):

To be exact, it's neither `<` nor `<=`, it is defaulted to `std::less`. That one in turn calls `<` for most types, except where it is specialized. For example, `<` for pointers does not *generally* give a strict ordering, while `std::less` does.

Comment: `<` for pointers does not give a strict ordering **unless** the pointers point to objects in the same array or one-past-the-end.

Comment: thanks, added a "*generally*" for that part (imo for the example the exact circumstances are not of much interest, only the fact that strict ordering is not always given)

Comment: Either way, algorithms are specified in terms of `operator<`, not `std::less` ($25.4[alg.sorting]/1)

Answer (score 2):

It does indeed use `operator<` unless you provide a custom comparison. But the definition of "sorted" is not `a[n] < a[n+1]` (which we might call "strictly sorted"), but `!(a[n+1] < a[n])`; so equal elements are considered sorted. This is equivalent to using `<=`, but (in common with all other standard algorithms) doesn't require that operator to be defined.

In general, all ordered comparisons must define a "strict weak ordering". "Strict" means that the comparison must be false for equivalent objects; so `<` is valid, while `<=` is not.

Comment: Is it really `std::less`? 25.4/1 says `All the operations in 25.4 have two versions: one that takes a function object of type Compare and one that uses an operator<.`

Comment: @Cubbi: You're right; I was assuming it would be the same as the ordered containers, but the algorithms do indeed specify `operator<`.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the example implementation, `<` is used for checking if the **next** element is **less** than the previous one:

```
if (*next < *first)
    return next;
```

If it is, then the order is broken, and the function returns. I. e. the logic is reversed - the algorithm does not terminate if the next element is equal to the previous.