# std::set with personal comparison function have identical values

Tags: c++, stdset

I want to store a `std::set` of `Point3D` object, my comparison function is defined as follows (lexicographic order):

```
bool operator<(const Point3D &Pt1, const Point3D &Pt2)
{
    const double tol = 1e-5;

    if(fabs(Pt1.x() - Pt2.x()) > tol)
    {
        return Pt1.x() < Pt2.x();
    }    
    else if(fabs(Pt1.y() - Pt2.y()) > tol)
    {
        return Pt1.y() < Pt2.y();
    }
    else if(fabs(Pt1.z() - Pt2.z()) > tol)
    {
        return Pt1.z() < Pt2.z();
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

In some case the `set` contains identical point, I think the problem come from the comparison function, but I don't find exactly the problem. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Your comparison operator needs to implement strict weak ordering: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/979759/operator-and-strict-weak-ordering

Comment: So the question is: how to implement strict weak ordering with `double` and tolerance?

Comment: Well your code currently only tests each x,y,z coords individually, you'd need to test if all are less than epsilon and then return false

Comment: @EdChum but if all three differences are less than epsilon, operator  returns false as it is.

Comment: These seem to be points in space. Have you considered using Euclidean distance for ordering? The tolerance would be simpler to implement.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your tolerance concept does not correctly establish a [strict weak ordering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_ordering#Strict_weak_orderings), since it is not transitive. For the sake of example, imagine the tolerance were `1`. Now consider:

```
a = 1
b = 2
c = 3
```

here: `!(a<b)` and `!(b<c)`, but `a<c`. This is a clear violation of the transitivity requirement for a strict weak ordering.

If you want to implement a comparison that has tolerance, but which also is a strict weak ordering, you have to round every value in a consistent fashion (eg, `1.5 => 2`, `0.75 => 1`, `2.3 => 2`, etc) and then compare the rounded values.

Doing this seems very pointless, as `double`s already do this, but at the maximum possible precision. You'll still get strange behaviour when you find that `1.4999999... != 1.5`.

You should just write your comparator as follows, and abandon the tolerance concept:

```
bool operator<(const Point3D &Pt1, const Point3D &Pt2)
{
    //This can be replaced with a member/free function if it is used elsewhere
    auto as_tie = [](Point3D const &Pt) {
        //assumes the member functions return references
        //to the internal `Point3D` values.
        return std::tie(Pt.x(), Pt.y(), Pt.z());
    };
    return as_tie(Pt1) < as_tie(Pt2);
}
```

If you absolutely *must* have a tolerance, round the values as soon as they are put into the `Point3D`, or round the values immediately before the comparison (depending on the other requirements in your system).

Comment: In my case I need use of tolerance and round value just before comparison: `static_cast<int>(xDouble*std::pow(10,nbDecimal)+0.5)` for each coords.