# C++ std::set and std::multiset

Tags: c++, set, containers, std, multiset

In C++ by default both `std::set` and `std::multiset` have `std::less<T>` as their comparator. Can anyone please explain how does `std::multiset` allow duplicates and `std::set` does not?

Answer (score 7):

Both start with the equivalent an `upper_bound` on the existing contents to find the correct insertion point for the new item.

`std::set` then checks whether that found an existing item with a key equal to the new key, and if so returns, signaling failure.

`std::multiset` just inserts the new item at that point (and if it didn't return in the step above, `std::set` does the same).

Comment: I think std::set is checking for equivalence, not equality, isn't it? In particular, one can use a type that only defines `operator<` (strict weak ordering), but not `operator==`.

Comment: Does this mean the return value of `upper_bound` can be effectively used as a hint to `insert`?

Comment: @Lingxi probably, but it is not going to improve on the total number of comparisons required to insert, since you pay for the `upper_bound`.

Answer (score 4):

To follow up on Jerry's answer, note that `std::set` and `std::multiset` assume that the elements are comparable via a [strict weak ordering](https://stackoverflow.com/q/979759/3093378) by `operator<`. In particular, the elements **do not have to be comparable under `operator==`**.  `std::set` only allows *non-equivalent* elements, whereas `std::multiset` allows in addition *equivalent* elements. This is slightly different from equality/non-equality. Two elements `A` and `B` are equivalent whenever `!(A < B) && !(B < A)`, and it is this latter condition that is checked by `std::set::insert`, and if true, the element is not inserted.

Example [<kbd>Live on Ideone</kbd>](http://ideone.com/vukr2V)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <set>

struct Foo
{
    int _x, _y, _z;
    Foo(int x, int y, int z): _x(x), _y(y), _z(z) {}
    bool operator<(const Foo& rhs) const // weak majorization
    {
        return (_x < rhs._x) && (_x + _y < rhs._x + rhs._y) &&
               (_x + _y + _z < rhs._x + rhs._y + rhs._z) ; 
    }
};

int main()
{
    std::set<Foo> setFoo;
    // try to insert 2 equivalent elements
    setFoo.insert(Foo{1, 2, 3}); 
    if(setFoo.insert(Foo{1, 2, 0}).second == false) // failed to insert
        std::cout << "Equivalent element already in the set!" << std::endl;
}
```