# Is it undefined behaviour to change sort order while sorting?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

Imagine the following scenario:

```
std::atomic<int>  values[10];
std::size_t      indices[10];

void sort() {
    std::iota(indices, indices+10, 0);

    std::sort(indices, indices+10,
        [&](size_t lhs, size_t rhs) { return values[lhs] < values[rhs]; });
}
```

While running the `sort()`, another thread is changing `values`. Will this merely result in indices not being correctly ordered afterwards, or is it actually undefined behaviour?

Comment: Quicksort may rely on the fact that there are elements smaller and higher than the pivot during the scans. If you break this property, the algorithm can go nuts.

Comment: I don't know for sure.  Instinctively, I would place such an action in the 'batshit crazy' category.

Comment: Martin James: It looks glaring in this example, because all irrelevant details are removed. A more subtle use case where the same question arises would be sorting a vector of shared_ptr by their use count.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Probably* (see below) it's undefined behavior; in practice, I've seen plain crashes (for out of container boundary access) even just for incorrect (=not inducing a total ordering) comparators, and `<` with indexes changed while sorting surely fails to induce a total ordering

Interestingly, the standard doesn't explicitly mention undefined behavior regarding this issue; C++11 §5.4 ¶3 just states that

> For algorithms other than those described in 25.4.3 to work correctly, `comp` has to induce a strict weak ordering on the values.

and I fail to see a formal definition of "work correctly" looking around there; even just the word "undefined" isn't ever uttered in the whole chapter 25 (which describes `<algorithm>`).

Comment: Just to play the devil's advocate, couldnt the crashes also be caused by the standard library implementing the c++ standard incorrectly?

Comment: @Benno: in facts I'm looking up a quotation in the standard.

Comment: This may not be an explicit mandate, but I believe that since the Standard does not define what should happen, that therefore that makes it undefined behaviour.

Comment: That wording was fixed by a recent-ish LWG issue to be a "shall" requirement, and I'm fairly sure there's global wording in the library introduction making violating such requirements UB.

Answer (score 2):

std::sort requires a sorter which satisfies the strict weak ordering rule.
(Explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/979759/operator-and-strict-weak-ordering/981299#981299))

If you change the contents simultaneously, this ordering may not maintain and thus results in undefined behaviour. (Can cause infinite loop in sorter, a crash, indices not being correctly ordered afterwards(as you mentioned), indices correctly sorted, 2 moons or something else)