# c++ working with maps of structs

Tags: c++, struct, iterator, operator-overloading

Point is a struct of the form:

```
typedef struct Point {
    int x;
    int y;
    bool operator<(const Point &other) const
    {
        return ((this->x < other.x) && (this->y < other.y));
    };
    bool operator!=(const Point &other) const
    {
        return ((this->x != other.x) || (this->y != other.y));
    }
    bool operator==(const Point &other) const
    {
        return ((this->x == other.x) && (this->y == other.y));
    }
} Point;
```

and I'm using:

```
map<Point,int> points;
```

the map is initialized with {{0,0},1}. and the program used points.count(p) to check whether the point p is a key in the points map.
There's a problem and the program always returns yes! even for points not in the map. I mean if p is not a key in points, I'm getting points.count(p)==1 (and not 0).
Also, when using points.find(p) to get the iterator to check whether the received point is really ==0 (it is not), I'm getting a reference to a totally different point..
Any idea how to fix the problem?

Comment: Your `operator<` does not define a [*Strict Weak Ordering*](https://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/StrictWeakOrdering.html).

Comment: You are correct, when I initialize points with Point={0,0} and int = 1; I receive that {1,1} is not a key whereas {0,1} is.. how  do I fix that?. Edit: @BoBTFish hey I missed your link, now I'm checking that out

Comment: [This question has answers for 3 points](http://stackoverflow.com/q/979759/1171191).

Comment: @BoBTFish I've just updated according to the first link, and it works! thank you very much Bob

Comment: Also, the `typedef struct Point {...} Point;` construction is only relevant in C, not C++.

Comment: @BoBTFish Then what is the better option? class of Point?

Comment: Just `struct Point {...};` is fine. The only difference between `struct` and `class` is `public`/`private` by default respectively.

Comment: @BoBTFish uh ok, thanks Bob

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `operator<()` is badly defined. Suppose I have `a=Point{0,1}` and `b=Point{1,1}`. Then neither `a<b` nor `b<a` nor `a==b` is true, which makes the operator not an ordering on the set of possible points. In order to correct this you need to make one of the dimensions (say x) the 'major' dimension in your comparison:

```
bool operator<(const Point &other) const
{
    return ((this->x < other.x) || 
             ((this->x == other.x) && (this->y < other.y));
};
```