# Why can't I map a structure in C++?

Tags: c++, mapping, structure

I've declared a structure like this ->

```
struct data{
    int x,y;
    bool operator < (const data& other) {
        return x<other.x or y<other.y;
    }
};
```

Now I want to `map` it as a key and with a `bool` value.

```
int main()
{
    data a;
    map<data,bool>mp;
    a.x=12, a.y=24;
    mp[a]=true;
}
```

The last line gives me this error ->

```
error: passing 'const' as 'this' argument of 'bool data::operator<(const data&)' discards qualifiers
```

How can I fix this ??

Comment: it is equivalent to `||`

Comment: Also, `and` is equivalent to `&&` :)

Comment: @Ajay [See this](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_alternative)

Comment: Yeah, but from where it is coming? The code you post here should compile everywhere! :)

Comment: Ah! Thanks. It coming from `<iso646.h>`

Comment: @Ajay In C, yes. But in C++ it's built into the language

Comment: You didn't ask about this, but `x<other.x or y<other.y` is wrong. If you define `data a={1,2}, b={2,1};` you will find that `a` and `b` are both less than each other (`a<b and b<a` is true) which will cause problems if you try to insert `a` and `b` in the map. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/37269108/1639256.

Comment: @Oktalist Thanks a lot. Yeah, I know that it was wrong. I wrote it just as a demo. But I also don't know the logic behind mapping a structure! Would you please tell me how to design the logic to map a structure ??

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`std::map<Key, Value>` internally stores them as `std::map<const Key, Value>`. The important thing here is that the `Key` is `const`.

So, in your example, `data` is `const`, but `operator<` is not! You cannot call a non-const method from a const object, so the compiler complains.

You'll have to specify `operator<` as `const`:

```
bool operator<(const data& other) const { /*...*/ }
                                  ^^^^^
```

Comment: Thank! It works :) Just tell me one more thing! Does it work fine when I compare two `data` type structures outside like `a<b` ??

Comment: @JishnuBanerjee why not? :)

Comment: @JishnuBanerjee a `const` method can be called on a non-const variable, but the reverse is not allowed.