# How does std:map check whether two objects are equal?

Tags: c++, stdmap

Why does the following code print `1`, even though I insert two elements into the map?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <utility>

struct Foo
{
  Foo(int bar, const std::string& baz)
    : bar(bar)
    , baz(baz)
  {}

  int bar;
  std::string baz;

  bool operator<(const Foo& rhs) const
  {
    if (bar < rhs.bar && baz < rhs.baz)
    {
      return true;
    }
    else
    {
      return false;
    }
  }
};

int main()
{
    Foo first(0, "test");
    Foo second(1, "test");
    std::map<Foo, std::string> m;
    m.insert(std::make_pair(first, "test"));
    m.insert(std::make_pair(second, "test1"));
    std::cout << m.size() << std::endl;
}
```

The second call to `insert()` says that we already have that item in the map. Why?

My [previous question](/q/39979773) was mistakenly closed because of the typo. I know that `insert` will tell you whether that item is already in the container.

Comment: `operator<` must define a strict weak ordering. Yours does not.

Comment: @Pubby What do you mean by "strict weak ordering"?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/979759/operator-and-strict-weak-ordering

Comment: Sorry the dupe was wrong.  Your title does not match the problem

Comment: Define your operator as `return bar != rhs.bar ? bar < rhs.bar : baz < rhs.baz;`

Comment: @Pubby Better yet, use `std::tie`.

Comment: The test is if( !(a < b) && !(b < a) ) a and b are equal.

Comment: @Pubby Can I just do `return bar < rhs.bar || baz < rhs.baz`?

Comment: Think about putting two-letter words in alphabetical order. That is an example of strict weak ordering. Same thing here, just instead of two letters you have an `int` and a `string`.

Comment: https://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/StrictWeakOrdering.html

Comment: Your question was not closed because of a typo. Read the duplicate.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The map's `insert()` uses the `operator<` you provided to decide equivalence between elements.  If `a < b` and `b < a` are both false, then the two elements are considered equal.

Your `operator<()` is inconsistent because it doesn't define the necessary [strict weak ordering](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/Compare).  For example, consider `a.bar < b.bar` and `b.baz < a.baz`; then `a < b` is false and `b < a` is false, so the map believes `a == b`.

In your specific case, when comparing `first` and `second`, then `first.baz` and `second.baz` are both `"test"`, so both comparisons return false, and the elements are considered equal.

You need something like:

```
bool operator<(const Foo& rhs) const
{
    return std::tie(bar, baz) < std::tie(rhs.bar, rhs.baz);
}
```

Comment: Can I just do `return bar < rhs.bar || baz < rhs.baz`?

Comment: @FrozenHeart: No.

Comment: @FrozenHeart you can do whatever you want, as complicated or as simple as you desire, but if it doesn't comply with [strict weak ordering restrictions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_ordering#Strict_weak_orderings) , it isn't going to work. That does not. In your case, `return bar < rhs.bar || (!(rhs.bar < bar) && (baz < rhs.baz))`, which `std::tie` couplings will give you  (and thus why it is encouraged).

Comment: If you don't like `std::tie()`, you could `return bar!=rhs.bar ? bar < rhs.bar : baz != rhs.baz ? baz < rhs.baz :  /* more tests */ : false;`.  But you won't get the necessary ordering by simply combining those two tests with boolean operators.  I encourage you to work through the possibilities in your head or on paper to see why they won't work.