# Getting Memory Corruption (Malloc) while using new operator and calling constructor of a structure in C++

Tags: c++, algorithm, new-operator

I was trying [this problem](https://www.interviewbit.com/problems/merge-overlapping-intervals/)  and I am not concerned with the logic or algorithm of this program right now. My concern is I am getting the segmentation fault. For that I tried using gdb which showed me a "malloc : memory corruption". This problem has been haunting me as many times I use new operator and get segmentation fault. I am not able to figure out why?. But tracing output on a test case made me think something is wrong with the while loop. Please help me to correct my mistake.

Here is my code [link](https://ideone.com/hBIfgt), I was struggling to properly insert code on stackoverflow so used ideone. It also has the test case for which It gives segmentation fault.

I am getting following error message.
*** Error in `./mergeoverlapping': malloc(): memory corruption: 0x0000000000a8e130 ***

Aborted

---

(program exited with code: 134)
Press return to continue

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
// debug statement
#define TRACE
#ifdef TRACE
#define trace1(x) cerr << #x << ": " << x << endl;
#define trace2(x, y)                                                           \
  cerr << #x << ": " << x << " | " << #y << ": " << y << endl;
#define trace3(x, y, z)                                                        \
  cerr << #x << ": " << x << " | " << #y << ": " << y << " | " << #z << ": "   \
       << z << endl;
#define trace4(a, b, c, d)                                                     \
  cerr << #a << ": " << a << " | " << #b << ": " << b << " | " << #c << ": "   \
       << c << " | " << #d << ": " << d << endl;
#define trace5(a, b, c, d, e)                                                  \
  cerr << #a << ": " << a << " | " << #b << ": " << b << " | " << #c << ": "   \
       << c << " | " << #d << ": " << d << " | " << #e << ": " << e << endl;
#define trace6(a, b, c, d, e, f)                                               \
  cerr << #a << ": " << a << " | " << #b << ": " << b << " | " << #c << ": "   \
       << c << " | " << #d << ": " << d << " | " << #e << ": " << e << " | "   \
       << #f << ": " << f << endl;
#else
#define trace1(x)
#define trace2(x, y)
#define trace3(x, y, z)
#define trace4(a, b, c, d)
#define trace5(a, b, c, d, e)
#define trace6(a, b, c, d, e, f)

#endif

// Structure of Interval defined by nterviewbit
struct Interval {
  int start;
  int end;
  Interval() : start(0), end(0) {}
  Interval(int s, int e) : start(s), end(e) {}
};

// operator just in case I needed sorting
bool compare(Interval a, Interval b) {
  if (a.start < b.start)
    return true;
  if (a.end < b.end)
    return true;
  return false;
}

// swap function to check if start is greater than end , if so then swap them
void swapp(Interval *t) {
  if (t->start > t->end) {
    int p = t->end;
    t->end = t->start;
    t->start = p;
  }
}

class Solution {
public:
  vector<Interval> merge(vector<Interval> &A) {
    vector<Interval> ans;
    sort(A.begin(), A.end(), compare);
    for (int i = 0; i < (int)A.size(); i++) {
      trace2(A[i].start, A[i].end);
      swapp(&A[i]);
      trace2(A[i].start, A[i].end);
    }
    int j = 0;
    int sz = A.size();
    while (j < sz) {
      while (j + 1 < sz and
             max(A[j].start, A[j + 1].start) <= min(A[j].end, A[j + 1].end)) {
        Interval *x = new Interval(min(A[j].start, A[j + 1].start),
                                   max(A[j].end, A[j + 1].end));
        trace2(x->start, x->end);
        trace2(A[j].start, A[j].end);
        A[j] = *x;
        trace2(A[j].start, A[j].end);
        trace2(A[j + 1].start, A[j + 1].end);
        A[j + 1] = *x;
        trace2(A[j + 1].start, A[j + 1].end);
        j++;
        delete x;
      }
      ans.push_back(A[j]);
      j++;
    }
    // for(int i=0;i<ans.size();i++){
    //     printf("i %d [%d %d]",i,ans[i].start,ans[i].end);
    //     cout<<endl;
    // }
    return ans;
  }
};
// BEGIN CUT HERE

int main() {
  Solution *obj = new Solution();
  // x denotes the number of intervals
  int x;
  cin >> x;
  vector<Interval> v;
  // an interval input consist of 2 integers start and end marked by a and b
  // respectively
  for (int i = 0; i < x; i++) {
    int a, b;
    cin >> a >> b;
    Interval *interval = new Interval(a, b);
    trace2(interval->start, interval->end);
    v.push_back(*interval);

    delete interval;
  }
  vector<Interval> ans = obj->merge(v);
  for (int i = 0; i < (int)ans.size(); i++) {
    printf("i %d [%d %d]", i, ans[i].start, ans[i].end);
    cout << endl;
  }
}
```

Comment: you need to `delete` things you've `new`ed up, not `free`

Comment: You appear to be using `free` on something allocated with `new`.

Comment: Stop using pointers and `new`. You don't need any of those in this program. If you came to C++ from Java, forget all you know about it and start afresh. C++ is completely different, none of your experience translates.

Comment: @Stargateur, I apologise for posting screenshot, I removed it and wrote the message instead.

Comment: @MikeVine,   I tried both but it does not change anything

Comment: @n.m. so how would I call the constructor then?

Comment: @NeilButterworth, I tried both but it does not change anything

Comment: @NeilButterworth, can you tell if I am accessing any memory, I should not have.

Comment: Like this: `ClassName variable(ctorArg1, ctorArg2);` or like this `callingAFunction(ClassName(ctorArg1, ctorArg2));`. It looks like you need to read a C++ book. This question is so basic, it is unclear how you plan to ever write anything at all in C++ without being able to answer it.

Comment: If you want any help, you need to post an example of input file which causes your program to crash.

Comment: @n.m. can you please click the link code I have put, it contains the test case as well

Comment: @n.m. did that help?

Comment: It did but you should post it in the question itself.

Comment: Don't use #define for functions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A comparator for `std::sort` must define a **strict weak ordering** (explained e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/979759/operator-and-strict-weak-ordering/981299#981299)).

Your comparator doesn't. Try to compare two intervals (2,3) and (1,4), then the same intervals in the reverse order.

Thus the behaviour is undefined and your `sort` function may crash, or worse, corrupt the memory arena and cause a crash later.

Changing the comparator to e.g.

```
 return a.start < b.start || a.start == b.start && a.end < b.end
```

should fix this crash.

Comment: @Thank you very much n.m. for thr help. I always doubted that something is wrong with the way I work with new and pointers but learned a new thing today . Would you suggest me more elegant ways to work with new and pointer?

Comment: The most elegant way to work with new and pointers is to avoid them entirely, which is very doable with this program.