# In which case a insert in a std::map can fail?

Tags: c++, dictionary

In my code I have those lines:

```
if(mymap.count(plan) == 0) {
    std::vector<XYZ> v;
    v.reserve(10);
    mymap.emplace(plan, v);
    std::cout << "Plan " << plan.normal << " @ " << plan.O << " added";
}

//I inserted this code for debugging
std::map<Plan, std::vector<XYZ>>::const_iterator it = mymap.find(plan);
if(it == this->intersections.end())
    std::cout << "not found";
```

How is it possible that I can read in the console `plan added` and just after `not found` ?

My map is declared as such:

```
std::map<Plan, std::vector<XYZ>, PlanComp> mymap;
```

At some point I thougt it comes from the comparator, but it respects irreflexivity, antisymmetry, transitivity, transitivity of equivalence (which is enough according to [this blog](http://fusharblog.com/3-ways-to-define-comparison-functions-in-cpp/)) :

```
struct PlanComp {
  bool operator()(const Plan& l, const Plan& n) const {
    return (l.O.x != n.O.x) || (l.O.y != n.O.y) || (l.O.z != n.O.z)
            || (l.normal.x != n.normal.x) || (l.normal.y != n.normal.y) || (l.normal.z != n.normal.z);
  }
};

struct XYZ {
    double x;
    double y;
    double z;
};

struct Plan {
    XYZ O;
    XYZ plan;
};
```

Comment: The comparator should be exhibiting "less than" semantics - AKA a strict weak ordering.  Yours doesn't appear to do so.

Comment: I don't think your "comparator" respects antisymmetry or transitivity.

Comment: That's not sufficient for defining an order.

Comment: @Deewy, `std::map` is an ordered container, use `std::unordered_map` if you don't need ordering

Comment: @LogicStuff I did tried a quick fix by replacing `!=` by `<` and did not work. Would you suggest trying to compare euclidian distance between `O` and the same for `normal` ?

Comment: Use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37269108/3552770) (also linked in the answer).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your comparator does not define a [strict weak ordering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_ordering#Strict_weak_orderings) (loosely speaking, "less than" semantics which define an order for your elements).  Therefore your code exhibits undefined behaviour.

The simplest solution would be to use a *lexicographical* comparator - compare `x` first, then compare `y` only in the event of a tie, and so on.  In C++11 that's even simpler; `operator <` for tuples already does this for you (and you can use `std::tie` to get the tuples).  See the answers to [*Operator < and strict weak ordering*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/979759/operator-and-strict-weak-ordering/37269108) for examples.