# Find if two variables are equal only with less than operator

Tags: c++, algorithm, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

I am trying to implement a binary search tree and I need a function which tells me if an element already exists in the tree or not!
However the only operator I can use is **<** .
Is this even possible?

I have already
tried `(a<b) || (b<a)` and `!(a<b) && !(b<a)`

Note: I am only allowed to use **<** to compare my elements in the binary tree.

Comment: There are only 2 possible things you can do: `a < b` and `b < a`. Think about it - what if neither of those are true?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Operator< and strict weak ordering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/979759/operator-and-strict-weak-ordering)

Comment: If neither of two values are less than the other, they must be equal.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can write in C++

```
not ( a < b or b < a )
```

that is equivalent to

```
not ( a < b ) and not ( b < a )
```

Though for the binary search tree that expression is not required because usually it is enough to use `if_else` statements like

```
if ( a < b )
{
    // ...
}
else if ( b < a )
{
    //...
}
else /* a == b */
{
    //...
}
```

Comment: @Xirema There is no need the exact equality for float numbers.

Comment: It's still not guaranteed to work for floats either. `NaN` values can cause situations where `a<b`, `b<a`, and `a==b` all return false.

Comment: @Xirema I have already  answered your comment. Do not repeat yourself.

Comment: In your code, storing a value with `NaN` can cause a search for `2.5` to return the value stored at `NaN`. That cannot possibly be correct code.

Comment: @Xirema By the way you can make a proposal to the C++ Standard Committee to rewrite all standard algorithms that are based on the operator <. Good luck.:)

Comment: Most STL algorithms have as a precondition that the key being searched is weakly ordered, and leave it as undefined behavior if it isn't. The OP did not specify a precondition that their key is weakly ordered.

Comment: @Xirema Using only operator < implies this.

Comment: @Xirema One more write your own proposal to the C++ Standard Committee. What is the problem?:)

Comment: Why do you keep suggesting to write proposals to the C++ committee? I'm not talking about STL algorithms or anything having to do with the standard library. I'm talking about your specific assertion, that `!(a < b || b < a)` fully establishes equality between two objects, **which is false**, even with basic arithmetic types (floats have `NaN`, ints have the potential for a ones-compliment representation which may fail this check).

Comment: @Xirema It seems you understand nothing. I advice to investigate assoative ordered containers like std::set or std::map and some standard algorithms especially with the snames starting with set_xxx. By the way binary search tree is also based on algorithms. I advice you to write a proposal because what you are saying me is not interesting to me.

Answer (score 4):

**You cannot guarantee, given only an implementation of `operator<`, that `a == b`.**

This is because there exists a concept called "Partial Ordering", which may, under unusual circumstances, permit a scenario where two objects can be *conditionally* ordered against each other.

Consider, as an example, a graph describing class inheritance. We could define the following rules:

- Class `A` is equal to Class `B` if `A` and `B` describe the same class.
- Class `A` is greater than Class `B` if `A` is a superclass of `B` or is a superclass of a superclass of `B` or so on (`B` inherits from `A`, or `B` inherits from `C` which inherits from `A`, etc.)
- Class `A` is less than Class `B` if `A` is a subclass of `B` (`A` inherits from `B`, or `A` inherits from `C` which inherits from `B`, etc.)
- Class `A` **is not ordered with respect to** Class `B` if they have no relation to each other (`A` does not inherit from `B`, and `B` does not inherit from `A`)
- Class `A` **is not ordered with respect to** Class `B` if they both inherit from the same superclass, but otherwise have no relation (`A` inherits from `C`, `B` inherits from `C`)
- Class `A` **is not ordered with respect to** Class `B` if they are mutually inherited from the same subclass, but otherwise have no relation (`C` inherits from both `A` and `B`)

This makes it fully plausible that, given the following function:

```
std::string compare(T const& a, T const& b) {
    if(a == b) 
        return "Equal to";
    else if(a < b) 
        return "Less than";
    else if(a <= b) 
        return "Less than or Equal to";
    else if(a > b) 
        return "Greater than";
    else if(a >= b) 
        return "Greater than or Equal to";
    else 
        return "Unordered to";
}
```

The output could be `"Unordered to"`, given some inputs.

The **only** way to guarantee that two generic arguments are equal to each other is to have an overload for `operator==`.

Now, the good news for you is that if you're constructing a Binary Search Tree, there's an unwritten convention that the types being used to compare against should be, at the very least, weakly ordered (which means `a==b` will return the same as `!(a < b || b < a)`). So in your specific circumstances, so long as the provided *key* value is weakly ordered, `!(a < b || b < a)` will *always* return true when the objects are equal.

But you do need some mechanism to ensure the user doesn't try to pass a partially ordered key to your comparison function. Otherwise, you're stuck requiring a full `operator==` implementation.

P.S: Before someone jumps in and says "What about arithmetic types?", I would remind you that `NaN` exists for IEEE-compliant Floating point values, where `a < b` and `b < a` can both return false. `a == b` can also return false if both `a` and `b` are `NaN`, even if both `NaN` values have the same payload! Additionally, this relationship is **only guaranteed** for integers in a twos-compliment representation, which **the C++ standard does not require**.

Comment: Awesome answer. Detailed and explained everything I was confused about. Thank you

Comment: @Siyavash then mark this one as the actual right answer

Answer (score 2):

The expression you are looking for is:

```
!(a < b || b < a)
```

Which is equivalent to:

```
!(a < b) && !(b < a)
```

because of [Boolean algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_algebra) and [logical operators](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_logical).
Full example:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    int a = 2, b = 2;
    if (!(a < b || b < a)) {
        std::cout << "Are equal.";
    }
    else {
        std::cout << "Are not equal.";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As an illustration, you could do it for `ints` like this:

```
bool isEqual(int a, int b)
{
    if((!(a < b)) && (!(b < a)))
       return true;
    return false
}
```

If you cannot use even `&&` operator, you can just nest the if statements. There are more `()`s than needed, that's just for making more obvious the order of evaluation.

Comment: It's safe to assume the provided `operator<` returns `bool`. In that case, you can use `operator&&` as it's well defined for `bool`.