# Strange Behavior of std::set and < Operator Overloading?

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting, c++11, set

I understand that if the `<` operator is overloaded in C++ (for example, to insert custom structs into `std::set`), the implementation must be a [**strict weak order**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/979759/operator-and-strict-weak-ordering/981299#981299) over the underlying type.

Consider the following `struct` and implementation.  This implementation is not a strict weak order, but the code compiles and runs *without* throwing an error (I would expect it to throw an error, given the requirement of a strict weak order):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <set>
using namespace std;

struct Pixel {
    int x;
    int y;
};

bool operator < (Pixel lhs, Pixel rhs){
    return lhs.x < rhs.x || lhs.y < rhs.y;
};

int main(){
    set<Pixel> mySet;

    Pixel *newPixelA = new Pixel;
    newPixelA->x = 1;
    newPixelA->y = 3;

    Pixel *newPixelB = new Pixel;
    newPixelB->x = 4;
    newPixelB->y = 2;

    mySet.insert(*newPixelA);
    mySet.insert(*newPixelB);

}
```

Is this the expected behavior?  EDIT: using Xcode.

Comment: Undefined behavior is undefined. "Seems to work" is one possible manifestation of undefined behavior.

Comment: Your "appears to work" is indeed an accurate description of what you observed. It is also unclear why you are dynamically allocating source objects for insertion.

Comment: Try with more than 2 items.. Visual Studio thrown an exception immediately in a debug build.

Comment: Since you expect it to throw an error and it does not, why do you say it "appears to work just fine"? Isn't it not doing what you should expect it to do the very opposite of working just fine?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz good point; just edited

Comment: @RetiredNinja yes, I did run it; just edited question to be more clear

Comment: @RetiredNinja interesting observation about Visual Studio...maybe it's a behavior of Xcode (I'm using Xcode)

Comment: Short answer: if your comparison function doesn't conform to the requirement, your code has undefined behavior. You could get some sort of error message, or it could appear to work, or just about anything else. The standard simply places no requirement on the result.

Comment: Guess what: `char *p=nullptr; char c=*p;` will also compile. Doesn't mean that this will run successfully.

Answer (score 4):

The compiler has no way of determining whether your `operator<` is a strict weak ordering. Instead, what is meant by `std::set` requiring this is that it will only work correctly if you give it a strict weak ordering. It makes no guarantees about what will happen if you give it something else.

In general, what C++ means when it requires something is that it is *your* responsibility to make sure that something happens. If you do, then the compiler and library will guarantee that you get the right results.

Answer (score 1):

Standard guarantees expected behavior if comparator requirements are met. Otherwise, what happens depends on implementation and data sets. Your comparison function may work properly for some data sets (where for all points greater x implies greater y). Set cannot contain equal elements (as a math concept), and for `std::set` equivalence means equality, so it'll just prevent you from inserting value `a` if there is already value `b`, such that:

```
a < b == true
b < a == true
```

even though `a` may be not equal to `b`

Answer (score 1):

When the comparison operator implements strictly weak ordering of the contained elements, the objects in the `std::set` are ordered in a predictable patten. If not, there is no telling which object appears first in the `std::set` when you iterate over the objects.

Take the following sample program in which ordering of `Pixel1` is not done right and ordering of `Pixel2` is done right.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <set>

struct Pixel1 {
    int x;
    int y;
};

bool operator < (Pixel1 lhs, Pixel1 rhs){
    return lhs.x < rhs.x || lhs.y < rhs.y;
};

struct Pixel2 {
    int x;
    int y;
};

bool operator < (Pixel2 lhs, Pixel2 rhs){
    if ( lhs.x != rhs.x )
    {
       return (lhs.x < rhs.x);
    }
    return (lhs.y < rhs.y);
};

template <typename Pixel> void print(std::set<Pixel> const& mySet)
{
   for ( Pixel p : mySet )
   {
      std::cout << "(" << p.x << ", " << p.y << ") ";
   }
   std::cout << std::endl;
}

template <typename Pixel> void test1()
{
   std::set<Pixel> mySet;

   Pixel pixelA = {2, 3};
   Pixel pixelB = {4, 2};
   Pixel pixelC = {4, 1};

   mySet.insert(pixelA);
   mySet.insert(pixelB);
   mySet.insert(pixelC);

   print(mySet);
}

template <typename Pixel> void test2()
{
   std::set<Pixel> mySet;

   Pixel pixelA = {2, 3};
   Pixel pixelB = {4, 2};
   Pixel pixelC = {4, 1};

   mySet.insert(pixelB);
   mySet.insert(pixelA);
   mySet.insert(pixelC);

   print(mySet);
}

int main()
{
   std::cout << "Pixel1 ... \n";
   test1<Pixel1>();
   test2<Pixel1>();

   std::cout << "Pixel2 ... \n";
   test1<Pixel2>();
   test2<Pixel2>();
}
```

Output

```
Pixel1 ... 
(4, 1) (4, 2) (2, 3) 
(4, 1) (2, 3) (4, 2) 
Pixel2 ... 
(2, 3) (4, 1) (4, 2) 
(2, 3) (4, 1) (4, 2)
```

The order of objects in the `std::set<Pixel1>` depends on the order of insertion while the order of objects in the `std::set<Pixel2>` is independent of the order of insertion.

Only you can tell whether that is acceptable in your application,