# Sort Points Using C++

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting, opencv, point

I have an array of *std::vector<cv::Point>* that looks like-

```
[49, 500]
[49, 129]
[441, 501]
[49, 374]
[440, 374]
[440, 259]
[440, 128]
[49, 260]
```

Let consider array elements as *[x, y]*. Now I need to get 4 elements from the array having-

1. lowest x with highest y
2. lowest x with lowest y
3. highest x with lowest y
4. highest x with highest y

currently, I am using functions to sort based on conditions and then fetch a point.

```
bool SortForMinXMaxY(const Point & a, const Point &b) 
{
    return (a.x < b.x || a.y > b.y) ;
}
```

What should be the standard approach with C++ and OpenCV to achieve the goal?

Comment: Did you already have a look [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm)?

Comment: `>> lowest x value and highest y value` You seem to want AND but using OR here `return (a.x < b.x || a.y > b.y);`

Comment: && won't work here. Please rethink. @ Killzone Kid

Comment: @user0042 : I have looked there. But I have no clue which method should I use. Can you be a little more helpful, please?

Comment: @nsssayom  Look at [this](en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/lower_bound) or [this](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/upper_bound) maybe?

Comment: "lowest x value and highest y value" this is obviously not well defined. You'll need some metric or sth.

Comment: @user0042 I tried stable_sort. Returns the same. And not sure about lower_bound.

Comment: maybe you could find the point as "the point with lowest distance to the top left corner of the bounding rectangle", but no idea how to use that in a sorting. maybe just sth. like the closer2tlCorner point to the bounding rect of those two points?

Comment: @Micka Desired output for the failed case is [48, 498]

Comment: As @Micka says, what does "lowest x and highest y" mean?  How does a value with a very low x, but only a middling y compare to a value with a slightly higher x, but a considerably higher y?  Do you just want to compare x-y?

Comment: @MartinBonner I simply want to find out the point with Largest Y value and with Smallest X value.

Comment: So given the points (0,0) and (1,1) which one do you want?

Comment: but in your failed sample, the lowest x value is 47, not 48 and the highest y value is 502, not 498. Try return (a.x - a.y < b.x - b.y); However sorting will imho be slower than searching, if you only need a single point and not the complete sorted set of points.

Comment: @Micka: I am searching for a POINT not the highest and lowest values. I am looking for a point that has lowest X and at the same time highest Y possible.

Comment: So you basically just need the bounding box? What about cv::boundingRect(Points); ? You can then easily retrieve the four rectangle vertices

Comment: well, the lowest x is 47 and since there is no other point with 47, this is the winner? You must tell the algorithm your metric on how x and y work together if there is no point with LOWEST x (47 in example) and at the same time HIGHEST y (502 in example) but only points that lie in between. I wanted to show you that your criteria isn't well defined for your problem. Try the a.x-a.y < b.x-b.y thing, maybe that is enough (it will punish the diagonal, though) Imho the right metric would be the L2 distance to top left bounding box coordinate.

Answer (score 3):

The logic used in the compare function is not correct. It does not meet the requirements of [strictly weak ordering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/979759/operator-and-strict-weak-ordering).

Change it to:

```
bool SortForMinXMaxY(const Point & a, const Point &b) 
{
   if ( a.x != b.x )
   {
      return (a.x < b.x);
   }
   return (a.y > b.y);
}
```

Comment: No luck. Returns the same output as mine.

Comment: @nsssayom, I think there is a mismatch between your description of what you want to accomplish and the name of the function. I would change the last line to `return (a.y < b.y);` to match the description.

Comment: There is apparently no mismatch and your last edit returns the same output as my code did.

Comment: @nsssayom, please post a [mcve]. That would be helpful in providing further help.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem (finding *lowest x value **and** highest y value*) is **ILL-POSED**, since the lowest x value may be another point than the highest y value. You must not ask for both at the same point, but be clearer what you actually want. There are a number of possibilities:

1. The highest `y` amongst the points with lowest `x`

   ```
   [](Point const&a, Point const&b)
   { return a.x==b.x? a.y<b.y : a.x>b.x; }
   ```
2. the lowest `x` amongst the points with highest `y`

   ```
   [](Point const&a, Point const&b)
   { return a.y==b.y? a.x>b.x : a.y<b.y; }
   ```
3. the point with maximum difference `y-x`

   ```
   [](Point const&a, Point const&b)
   { return a.y-a.x < b.y-b.x; }
   ```

From your example, I guess it's the last one of these that you actually want, as `[48,498]` has neither the lowest x nor the highest y, but the largest difference.

Finally, for merely finding the maximum of (some function of) some values, you don't need to sort them, but merely do a single pass:

```
 auto extremum = std::max_element(Points.begin(), Points.end(),
                                  [](Point const&a, Point const&b)
                                  { return a.y-a.x < b.y-b.x; });
```

Answer (score 0):

The C++ sort function your are calling is quicksort, so each elemento will be evaluated multiple times. You need a more strict to make sure each possibility is evaluated by the function.

```
bool SortForMinXMaxY(const Point & a, const Point &b) 
{
   if ( a.x == b.x )
   {
      return (a.y > b.y);
   }
   if ( a.y == b.y)
   {
      return (a.x < b.x);
   }
   return (a.x < b.x || a.y > b.y);
}
```

Comment: this doesn't work!

Comment: Ok.
Has @rsahu solution worked?

Comment: Nope. that doesn't work too.

Comment: Wha is the result if you use"return (a.x < b.x && a.y > b.y) ;"?

Comment: I think my last edit or something close to it might work.

Comment: Using && won't work.  It isn't a strict weak ordering.

Comment: I thought so too. But doesn't work.

Comment: Well. if your array is not large you could try to use another sorting algorithm.

Comment: @Thadeu such as?

Comment: Bubble or InsectionSort. With these two you can sort the array twice, with diferente rules for each variable. InsectionSort would be far better. MergeSort might also work.