# Understanding a Comparator functor for STL

Tags: c++, c++11, stl, functor

So I have always used comparator functors in STL but never truly understood what returning a true or false meant. I had to run it and adjust the functor all the time. For instance suppose I have the following code

```
struct functor
{
    // does returning true place a before b ?
    bool operator()(int a,int b)
    {
        if (a < b)
            return true;
        return false;
    }
};

int main() 
{
    std::priority_queue<int, std::vector<int>,functor> q;
    for(int n : {1,8,5,6,3,4,0,9,7,2})
        q.push(n);
}
```

Could anyone please clarify this

```
bool operator()(int a,int b)
    {
        if (a < b)
            return true;
        return false;
    }
```

Does returning a true place `a` before `b`? I am trying to come up with something like "if a is less than b than return true and true means a will be placed before b" but apparently this is not correct

Comment: Functor simply should return `true` if its first argument (`a`) comes before its second argument (`b`) with respect to the required ordering.

Comment: See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/Compare

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, if your function is

```
bool operator(T a, T b);
```

If it returns true, it means that a is placed before b in the sorted ordering. However, the priority queue is ordered so that if a is placed before b, b will be higher than a in the queue. So if

```
bool operator (T a, T b) { return a < b; }
```

is used, the "largest" element will be at the top of the queue.

Answer (score 2):

You could always check the documentation.

From the [priority_queue](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/priority_queue):

```
template<
    class T,
    class Container = std::vector<T>,
    class Compare = std::less<typename Container::value_type>
> class priority_queue;
```

> Compare - A Compare type providing a strict weak ordering.

Then, check [Compare](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/Compare):

> The concept Compare is a set of requirements expected by some of the
>   standard library facilities from the user-provided function object
>   types.
>
> The return value of the function call operation applied to an object
>   of type Compare, when contextually converted to bool, *yields true if
>   the first argument of the call appears before the second in the strict
>   weak ordering relation induced by this Compare type, and false
>   otherwise*.

It means, that `functor::operator()` should accept two parameters (`a` and `b`) and return `true` if `a` "appears before" `b` while "appears before" rules are defined by the implementation of `functor::operator()` (this implementation must be compliant with the requirements imposed by `Compare` concept).

Comment: Important: for `priority_queue`, the order is the **reverse** of the order defined by the comparator. That is, calling `pop()` returns the **largest** element when the comparator is `<`. That's the nature of a priority queue; "normal" sorted containers follow the order defined by the comparator.

Answer (score -1):

It's convention to sort on `<`. Your code

```
bool operator()(int a,int b)
{
    if (a < b)
        return true;
    return false;
}
```

is the same as

```
bool operator()(int a, int b)
{
    return a < b ;
}
```

Also, have a look at [Operator< and strict weak ordering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/979759/operator-and-strict-weak-ordering)

Answer (score -1):

Why not just do this since it's simpler:

```
bool operator()(int a, int b)
{
    return a < b
}
```

The function you need to give as your sort function for the priority queue should by a binary function that returns true if b is bigger than a, or the first argument is bigger than b.

The sort function internally uses probably a simple swap of the two values if that condition is not true.

> Binary function that accepts two elements in the range as arguments, and returns a value convertible to bool. The value returned indicates whether the element passed as first argument is considered to go before the second in the specific strict weak ordering it defines.
>   The function shall not modify any of its arguments.
>   This can either be a function pointer or a function object.

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/sort/