# How to consider two structs equal regardless of their second attribute?

Tags: c++, compare

I have this structure

```
struct Event {
    const string event;
    const int order;
    Event(const string& _event, const int& _order):event(_event),order(_order) {}
};

struct EventCompare {
    bool operator()(const Event& lhs, const Event& rhs)
    {
        return (lhs.order < rhs.order);
    }
};
```

which I would like to use in a `set`:

```
set<Event, EventCompare> events;
```

I do know that sets doesn't allow duplicates. However, I would like to define duplicates as two instance of `structs` with equal `events` *regardless* of their orders, in other words, `A = B` iff `A.event == B.event`. This definition has to affect the way the set works, which means that, for example, the set has to ignore `Event("holiday", 1)`, if it already contains `Event("holiday", 0)`.

How can I do that? I've tried to add

```
if (lhs.event == rhs.event)
    return false;
```

in my `EventCompare`, but that didn't work. Will using `pair` instead of `struct` help anyhow?

Comment: Change `return (lhs.order < rhs.order);` to `return (lhs.event < rhs.event);` ?

Comment: @immibis That still wouldn't provide a correct ordering, since if the events are equal, it may return an incorrect value. `std::tie(x.event, x.order) < std::tie(y.event, y.order)`, will, however, guarantee to provide a correct ordering, albeit, it may not be what the OP wants.

Comment: Am I missing something? You say you want equal `events` and don't care about `order`. So why do you compare using: `return (lhs.order < rhs.order);`? Surely, based on what you've described, the obvious thing to use is: `return (lhs.event < rhs.event);`?

Comment: You can have a `std::set<Event>` ordered on `event`, and a `std::vector<std::reference_wrapper<Event>>` that you order on `order`.

Answer (score 2):

If under the conditions you specified they are considered to be equal, then it's obvious that the result of the `<` comparison would be false. One is not less than the other, they are considered to be equal. The comparison operator, for the purpose of being used with associative containers, only needs to indicate if one instance is "less" than the other. Since, under these circumstances, they are considered to be equal, neither one is less than the other.

Therefore:

```
struct EventCompare {
    bool operator()(const Event& lhs, const Event& rhs)
    {
        if (lhs.event == rhs.event)
             return false;

        return (lhs.order < rhs.order);
    }
};
```

However, this does not address the situation where two instances of the `Event` object have the same `order`, but different `Event`s. If such situation is cannot arise,  you don't have to worry about it. If it can, simply decide what their ordering would be, and set the return value of the comparison operator, in that case, accordingly.

Comment: Just FYI. I copied and pasted the code from your answer in mine.

Answer (score 2):

The closest you can use is:

```
struct EventCompare {
    bool operator()(const Event& lhs, const Event& rhs)
    {
        if (lhs.event == rhs.event)
             return false;

        return (lhs.order < rhs.order);
    }
};
```

However, the compare criteria you are asking for does not meet the [strictly weak ordering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/979759/operator-and-strict-weak-ordering), which is required to put objects in a `std::set`.

Let's you have three objects with the following data:

```
obj1 = {"foo", 200}
obj2 = {"bar", 300}
obj3 = {"foo", 400}
```

If you add objects to the set in the order `obj1`, `obj2`, `obj3`, you will see only `obj1` and `obj2`, in that order, in the set.

If you add objects to the set in the order `obj2`, `obj3`, `obj1`, you will see only `obj2` and `obj3`, in that order, in the set.

Not only do you get different objects in the set depending on which object is added to the set first but even the objects appear in different order based on which object was added to the set first. I can only see problems in the future if you follow this strategy.

I think you should take a fresh look at your requirements and look for a cleaner solution. I am not able to suggest a solution without a deeper understanding of what your are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

A `set` doesn't look for equality.  It only checks for an ordering.

Since you want two events to be equal if the `event` is the same, that means that neither comes before the other, and your comparison function should return `false` in that case.

```
bool operator()(const Event& lhs, const Event& rhs) const {
    return lhs.event != rhs.event && lhs.order < rhs.order;
}
```

**However**, this won't work since it no longer defines a *strict weak ordering*, since you can have events where `A < B` and `B < C` but `!(A < C)` if `A` and `C` have matching `event` strings but `B`'s order is between `A`'s and `C`'s.

So no, you can't use a set to store elements where a 2nd non-ordering attribute overrides the ordering one.  You'd have to change the ordering to be based on `event`, but then you won't be able to look things up based on the `order`.

You could use a `map` to map the `event` strings to the `order` value used to store them into the `set`.  Then you check the map to see if it is already there, and decide which element to keep in the set.  Otherwise update both the set and map with the new entry.

Answer (score 0):

I seem to be missing something blindingly obvious. But surely all you need to do is compare according to your requirements?

```
struct EventCompareName
{
    bool operator()(const Event& lhs, const Event& rhs)
    {
        // If you want to compare by event and not order, then do so.
        return (lhs.event < rhs.event);
        // Rather than comparing by order and not event.
        //return (lhs.order < rhs.order);
    }
};

std::set<Event, EventCompareName> events;
```

Of course, you might *also* want to compare by `order` in some cases (even though your question gives absolutely zero indication of that requirement). In which case:

```
struct EventCompareNameOrder
{
    bool operator()(const Event& lhs, const Event& rhs)
    {
        if (lhs.event != rhs.event)
            return (lhs.event < rhs.event);

        return (lhs.order < rhs.order);
    }
};

std::set<Event, EventCompareNameOrder> allEvents;
```