# How can I define the operator< for a struct?

Tags: c++, struct, operators

I have the srtucts:

```
struct Arco {

    int i, j;
    Arco () {};
    Arco (const Arco& obj): i(obj.i), j(obj.j) {};
    Arco(int _i, int _j) : i(_i), j(_j) {}    

};

struct ARCO_TEMPO {
    Arco a;
    int slotTimeU; 
    int slotTimeV; 
    ARCO_TEMPO () {};
    ARCO_TEMPO (const ARCO_TEMPO& obj): a(obj.a), slotTimeU(obj.slotTimeU), slotTimeV(obj.slotTimeV) {};
    ARCO_TEMPO (Arco _a, int _slotTimeU, int _slotTimeV) : a(_a), slotTimeU(_slotTimeU), slotTimeV(_slotTimeV) {}    

};

struct CICLO {
    set<ARCO_TEMPO> arco_tempo_order;
    set<int> arco_tempo_Aux;
    int aircraftType; 
    float COST;
    float reducedCost;
    float duracao;
    int numAircrafts;
    vector<bool> VisitedNodes; 
    vector<vector<bool>> VisitedVertices;
};
```

I need to define the operator< to the struct CICLO. As I want to order the CICLOs by their COSTs, I start the comparison by their COSTs. Next, I verify if the CICLOs are operated by the same aircraft, and then if they have the same amount of ARCOs_TEMPO.
If it is the case, I need to verify if these ARCOs_TEMPO are the same. 
Using these ideas, I wrote the code below:
(I wrote same couts to try to analyze where is the problem)

```
bool operator<(const CICLO& obj1, const CICLO& obj2) {

    cout << "obj1  = { aircraft type: "<< obj1.aircraftType << " " ;
    set<ARCO_TEMPO>::iterator itobj1;
    for (itobj1 = obj1.arco_tempo_order.begin();  itobj1 != obj1.arco_tempo_order.end(); itobj1++) {
        cout << "(" << itobj1->a.i+1 << "," << itobj1->a.j+1 << ")-("<<itobj1->slotTimeU<<", "<<itobj1->slotTimeV << "); ";
    }
    printf (" COST: %.0f }\n", obj1.COST);

    cout << "obj2  = { aircraft type: "<< obj2.aircraftType << " " ;
    set<ARCO_TEMPO>::iterator itobj2;
    for (itobj2 = obj2.arco_tempo_order.begin();  itobj2 != obj2.arco_tempo_order.end(); itobj2++) {
        cout << "(" << itobj2->a.i+1 << "," << itobj2->a.j+1 << ")-("<<itobj2->slotTimeU<<", "<<itobj2->slotTimeV << "); ";
    }
    printf (" COST: %.0f }\n", obj2.COST);

    if (obj1.COST < obj2.COST - 1) {
        cout << "1\n";
        return true;
    }
    else {
        if ( (abs(obj1.COST - obj2.COST) < 1) && obj1.aircraftType < obj2.aircraftType) {
            cout << "2\n";
            return true;
        }
        else {
            if (obj1.aircraftType == obj2.aircraftType && (abs(obj1.COST - obj2.COST) < 1) && obj1.arco_tempo_order.size() < obj2.arco_tempo_order.size()) {
                cout << "3\n";
                return true;
            }
            else {
                if (obj1.aircraftType == obj2.aircraftType && (abs(obj1.COST - obj2.COST) < 1) && obj1.arco_tempo_order.size() == obj2.arco_tempo_order.size()) {
                    bool igual = true;
                    set<ARCO_TEMPO>::iterator itobj1;
                    set<ARCO_TEMPO>::iterator itobj2;
                    for (itobj1 = obj1.arco_tempo_order.begin(), itobj2 = obj2.arco_tempo_order.begin();  itobj1 != obj1.arco_tempo_order.end(); itobj1++,itobj2++) {
                        if (igual && *itobj1 < *itobj2) {
                            cout << "4\n";
                            return true;
                        } 
                        else {
                            if (itobj1->a.i == itobj2->a.i && itobj1->a.j == itobj2->a.j && itobj1->slotTimeU == itobj2->slotTimeU && itobj1->slotTimeV == itobj2->slotTimeV) {
                                igual = true;
                            }
                            else {
                                cout << "5\n";
                                return false;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    cout << "6\n";
                    return false;
                }
                else{ 
                    cout << "7\n"; 
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

However, different cycles are being considered as equals.
I have a set of CICLOs:

```
set<CICLO>ConjCiclos;
```

I insert some inicial CICLOS in ConjCiclos, having ConjCiclos =

```
CICLO[1] = { aircraft type: 2; arco_tempo_order: (4,5)-(1, 2); (5,4)-(2, 3); (4,4)-(3, 4); (4,4)-(4, 5); (4,4)-(5, 6); (4,4)-(6, 7); (4,4)-(7, 1);  COST: 25000096 }
CICLO[2] = { aircraft type: 2; arco_tempo_order:  (1,5)-(1, 2); (5,1)-(2, 3); (1,1)-(3, 4); (1,1)-(4, 5); (1,1)-(5, 6); (1,1)-(6, 7); (1,1)-(7, 1);  COST: 25000142 }
CICLO[3] = { aircraft type: 2; arco_tempo_order:  (2,5)-(1, 2); (5,2)-(2, 3); (2,2)-(3, 4); (2,2)-(4, 5); (2,2)-(5, 6); (2,2)-(6, 7); (2,2)-(7, 1);  COST: 25000164 }
CICLO[4] = { aircraft type: 2; arco_tempo_order:  (1,2)-(1, 2); (2,1)-(2, 3); (1,1)-(3, 4); (1,1)-(4, 5); (1,1)-(5, 6); (1,1)-(6, 7); (1,1)-(7, 1);  COST: 25000220 }
CICLO[5] = { aircraft type: 2; arco_tempo_order:  (1,4)-(1, 2); (4,1)-(2, 3); (1,1)-(3, 4); (1,1)-(4, 5); (1,1)-(5, 6); (1,1)-(6, 7); (1,1)-(7, 1);  COST: 25000228 }
CICLO[6] = { aircraft type: 2; arco_tempo_order:  (2,4)-(1, 2); (4,2)-(2, 3); (2,2)-(3, 4); (2,2)-(4, 5); (2,2)-(5, 6); (2,2)-(6, 7); (2,2)-(7, 1);  COST: 25000232 }
CICLO[7] = { aircraft type: 2; arco_tempo_order:  (3,5)-(1, 2); (5,3)-(2, 3); (3,3)-(3, 4); (3,3)-(4, 5); (3,3)-(5, 6); (3,3)-(6, 7); (3,3)-(7, 1);  COST: 25000284 }
CICLO[8] = { aircraft type: 2; arco_tempo_order:  (3,4)-(1, 2); (4,3)-(2, 3); (3,3)-(3, 4); (3,3)-(4, 5); (3,3)-(5, 6); (3,3)-(6, 7); (3,3)-(7, 1);  COST: 25000326 }
CICLO[9] = { aircraft type: 2; arco_tempo_order:  (1,3)-(1, 2); (3,1)-(2, 3); (1,1)-(3, 4); (1,1)-(4, 5); (1,1)-(5, 6); (1,1)-(6, 7); (1,1)-(7, 1);  COST: 25000360 }
```

I try to add a different cycle to ConjCiclos:

```
CICLO[10] = { aircraft type: 2; arco_tempo_order:  (2,3)-(1, 2); (3,2)-(2, 3); (2,2)-(3, 4); (2,2)-(4, 5); (2,2)-(5, 6); (2,2)-(6, 7); (2,2)-(7, 1);  COST: 25000140 }
```

As we can see, CICLO[10] is a new CICLO to ConjCiclos, but it detects CICLO[10] as a redundant CICLO.

Debugging the code, I verify that it makes the comparasion of CICLO[10] as:

```
obj1  = { aircraft type: 2 (1,4)-(1, 2); (4,1)-(2, 3); (1,1)-(3, 4); (1,1)-(4, 5); (1,1)-(5, 6); (1,1)-(6, 7); (1,1)-(7, 1);  COST: 25000228 }
obj2  = { aircraft type: 2 (2,3)-(1, 2); (3,2)-(2, 3); (2,2)-(3, 4); (2,2)-(4, 5); (2,2)-(5, 6); (2,2)-(6, 7); (2,2)-(7, 1);  COST: 25000140 }
7
obj1  = { aircraft type: 2 (2,5)-(1, 2); (5,2)-(2, 3); (2,2)-(3, 4); (2,2)-(4, 5); (2,2)-(5, 6); (2,2)-(6, 7); (2,2)-(7, 1);  COST: 25000164 }
obj2  = { aircraft type: 2 (2,3)-(1, 2); (3,2)-(2, 3); (2,2)-(3, 4); (2,2)-(4, 5); (2,2)-(5, 6); (2,2)-(6, 7); (2,2)-(7, 1);  COST: 25000140 }
7
obj1  = { aircraft type: 2 (1,5)-(1, 2); (5,1)-(2, 3); (1,1)-(3, 4); (1,1)-(4, 5); (1,1)-(5, 6); (1,1)-(6, 7); (1,1)-(7, 1);  COST: 25000142 }
obj2  = { aircraft type: 2 (2,3)-(1, 2); (3,2)-(2, 3); (2,2)-(3, 4); (2,2)-(4, 5); (2,2)-(5, 6); (2,2)-(6, 7); (2,2)-(7, 1);  COST: 25000140 }
7
obj1  = { aircraft type: 2 (4,5)-(1, 2); (5,4)-(2, 3); (4,4)-(3, 4); (4,4)-(4, 5); (4,4)-(5, 6); (4,4)-(6, 7); (4,4)-(7, 1);  COST: 25000096 }
obj2  = { aircraft type: 2 (2,3)-(1, 2); (3,2)-(2, 3); (2,2)-(3, 4); (2,2)-(4, 5); (2,2)-(5, 6); (2,2)-(6, 7); (2,2)-(7, 1);  COST: 25000140 }
1
obj1  = { aircraft type: 2 (2,3)-(1, 2); (3,2)-(2, 3); (2,2)-(3, 4); (2,2)-(4, 5); (2,2)-(5, 6); (2,2)-(6, 7); (2,2)-(7, 1);  COST: 25000140 }
obj2  = { aircraft type: 2 (1,5)-(1, 2); (5,1)-(2, 3); (1,1)-(3, 4); (1,1)-(4, 5); (1,1)-(5, 6); (1,1)-(6, 7); (1,1)-(7, 1);  COST: 25000142 }
7
```

If I try to replace the operator< function to the one below:

```
bool operator<(const CICLO& lhs, const CICLO& rhs) { return std::tie(lhs.COST, lhs.aircraftType, lhs.arco_tempo_order) < std::tie(rhs.COST, rhs.aircraftType, rhs.arco_tempo_order); }
```

the same CICLO is added a lot of time.

I have for example both of CICLOs below added:

```
CICLO[11499] = { aircraft type: 2 (3,2)-(3, 4); (2,1)-(4, 5); (1,5)-(5, 1); (5,5)-(1, 2); (5,5)-(2, 3); (5,5)-(3, 4); (5,3)-(4, 5); (3,3)-(5, 1); (3,3)-(1, 2); (3,3)-(2, 3);  COST: 46000392.0000000000 }
CICLOIT[11500] = { aircraft type: 2 (3,2)-(3, 4); (2,1)-(4, 5); (1,5)-(5, 1); (5,5)-(1, 2); (5,5)-(2, 3); (5,5)-(3, 4); (5,5)-(4, 5); (5,3)-(5, 1); (3,3)-(1, 2); (3,3)-(2, 3);  COST: 46000392.0000000000 }
```

Does anyone know why it is happening?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Can you give us an example of two CICLOs, what the operator ought to return, and what it actually does return?

Comment: Simply use something like: `bool operator<(const CICLO& lhs, const CICLO& rhs) { return std::tie(lhs.COST, lhs.aircraftType, lhs.arco_tempo_order) < std::tie(rhs.COST, rhs.aircraftType, rhs.arco_tempo_order); }`

Comment: Even if COST, aircraftType and arco_tempo_order.size() are the same, I need to vrify each ARCO_TEMPO within arco_tempo_order to conclude if the two CICLOs are or not the same. So, I don't think I can use only what you said, @Jarod42!

Comment: `operator < (const std::set<T>&, const std::set<T>&)` is defined.

Comment: When I try to replace my operator< for yours, the same CICLO is generated a lot of times. I think that as COST is a float variable, and I am working with big and small values to calculate COST, I need to add some small value in the original COST. I think that it is considering equal CICLOS as different ones because of a little difference in COST values. I tried to add 1 in rhs.COST, but then a error message appears.

Answer (score 1):

The operator < has to have a "Strict Weak Ordering" for it to work correctly with the STL.

This statement:

```
if (obj1.COST < obj2.COST - 1) {
    return true;
}
```

Makes the condition untrue.

```
obj1.COST = 9;
obj2.COST = 10;

obj1 < obj2      false
obj2 < obj1      false
```

This implies the two objects are equal (all other things being the same).

Lets extend this to three objects.

```
obj1.COST = 9;
obj2.COST = 10;
obj3.COST = 11;

obj1 < obj2      false
obj2 < obj1      false
// So obj1 == obj2


obj2 < obj3      false
obj3 < obj2      false
// So obj2 == obj3

// This we should be able to assume:
obj1 == obj3
// Otherwise strict weak ordering is not working.


obj1 < obj3      true
obj3 < obj1      false
// So they are not equal.
// Something is very wrong and thus your set is not going to work.
```

Checkout this answer for  https://stackoverflow.com/a/37269108/14065 for an easy way to implement the solution.

Comment: The thing is that I am delaing with big values of COST. Then, I won't have CICLOS with cost difference of one unit.
I tried to replace my operator< for the one that @Jarod42! suggested, but in thta case, the same CICLO is added a lot of time.

Comment: @LuizaReal Basically you need to define the less than in a way that is consistent. Your method is not consistent. You need to think of another way of doing this (subtracting 1 from the rhs is not going to work). Comparing floating point values is always going to be tricky (try and avoid that (i.e. cast to integer).

Comment: Thank you, @MartinYork! I replace float by double and that worked.