# C++ long error message i cannot resolve

Tags: c++, clion

[image]

I get this message and it just goes on and on for ages and I can't see why.
It says there is a problem with the template usage maybe but I don't think I did something wrong:

```
using std::shared_ptr;
using std::set;

class User{
    set<CoinBalance> holdings;
    ApiConnection api;

public:
    void newHolding(const shared_ptr<Coin>&, double amount = 0);
    void addToHolding(const shared_ptr<Coin>&, double amount = 0);
    void decreaseFromHolding(const shared_ptr<Coin>&, double amount = 0);

    double getHondingsUsdValue();
};
```

and this is how I used `shared_ptr`:

```
class CoinBalance {
    shared_ptr<Coin> coin;
    double amount;
};
```

Comment: Please, can you provide thee error message in a snippet instead of an image ?

Comment: Going out on a limb, it looks like `std::set` requires a less compare (< operator) on `CoinBalance`, which isn't there by default.

Comment: Your `CoinBalance` class probably needs an `operator<` member since you're creating an `std::set` of them.

Comment: but i overloaded == and != isn't it enough for the set to compare?

Comment: no, becase set uses tree structure internally so less-than is required. you can try hash_set instead, but that needs equality operator and hash function.

Comment: Look up "strict weak ordering" and see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/979759/operator-and-strict-weak-ordering

Answer (score 1):

yes, you need to implement the < operator for CoinBalance

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to implement the operator '<' for class `CoinBalance`.