# C++ initialize a set of a structure

Tags: c++, struct, set

I am trying to create a set of a structure but my code keeps getting errors, and I can't find anything online.

```
struct smove {

    int src;
    int dst;
};

int main()
{

    smove moov;
    moov.dst = 1;
    moov.src = 2;
    set<struct smove> moovs = {moov};
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Post a [MCVE] including the exact error text verbatim her please.

Comment: So, what do the errors say?

Comment: *"my code keeps getting errors"* - For future reference, **always** include the full, verbatim error message in your post when you're posting about getting unexpected errors. In doing so, explain what you *think* they mean (if anything) and why you *don't* think that applies to your situation.

Comment: "`set<struct smove>`" - recovering C programmer? That `struct` is not needed in C++.

Comment: By the way, regarding "I can't find anything online", the answer is on the first page of a Google search for `C++ set`.

Answer (score 4):

Set's value type needs to be less-than comparable. That's how the container knows how elements relate to one another and in what order (including ensuring no duplicates).

Short story, make an `operator<` for `smove`.

The long story is, well, longer, because that operator is required to work in a certain way, but you can [read up on that](https://stackoverflow.com/q/979759/560648). For now, here's a simple example that uses `std::tie` to get a legal ordering quickly:

```
#include <set>
#include <tuple>

struct smove
{
    int src;
    int dst;
};

bool operator<(const smove& lhs, const smove& rhs)
{
    return std::tie(lhs.src, lhs.dst) < std::tie(rhs.src, rhs.dst);
}

int main()
{
    smove moov;
    moov.dst = 1;
    moov.src = 2;
    std::set<smove> moovs = {moov};
}
```

Comment: Very probable the problem identified, the question isn't yet completed though.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Meh, it's obvious what the problem is. I ain't waitin'.

Comment: Further Info: Many std containers have requirements. Until you become familiar with them all, recommend googling up each and reading through the requirements. For example, you'll find that a copy constructor is required for some, others a copy constructor and less than operator. Keep in mind what is generated and what needs to be implemented for each.