# Confusing result of std::sort (stable_sort) compare function return value

Tags: c++, sorting, std

I have the following simple program. In `test1` and `test2` I tried to sort 2 strings "2" and "1", and in the example below, the function `compare` will always return false.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cassert>

static inline bool compare(const std::string& a, const std::string& b)
{
    if (isdigit(b[0]))
        return false;

    assert(isdigit(a[0]));
    return true;
}

static inline void test1()
{
    std::cout << "test1:\n";
    std::vector<std::string> arr = {
            "2", "1"
    };
    std::stable_sort(arr.begin(), arr.end(), compare);
    for (auto e: arr)
        std::cout << e << std::endl;
}

static inline void test2()
{
    std::cout << "test2:\n";
    std::vector<std::string> arr = {
            "1", "2"
    };
    std::stable_sort(arr.begin(), arr.end(), compare);
    for (auto e: arr)
        std::cout << e << std::endl;
}

static inline bool compare_int(const int& a, const int& b)
{
    return a > b;
}

static inline void test3()
{
    std::cout << "test3:\n";
    std::vector<int> arr = {
            9, 3, 13, 7
    };
    std::stable_sort(arr.begin(), arr.end(), compare_int);
    for (auto e: arr)
        std::cout << e << ' ';
    std::cout << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    test1();
    test2();
    test3();

    return 0;
}
```

However, I get the following output

```
test1:
2
1
test2:
1
2
test3:
13 9 7 3
```

I'm confused, because as far as I know, the `compare` function in test1 and test2 will return false, which indicates that these 2 elements *should* swap their location. But obviously, they do not change and are still in their original location.

Am I misinterpreting the return value of compare function? But in `test3` it is indeed sorted in descending order.

I don't quite understand its internals, does it treat characters in a different way from integers?

Comment: I am the sorting function.  I call `compare("2", "1")`.  You return `false`.  Then I call `compare("1", "2")`.  You again return `false`.  See a problem?  Your compare function says that "2" comes after "1", and at the same time "1" comes after "2".  That's impossible, but that's what you coded.

Comment: Thanks, but if I add an output in compare function `std::cout << a << ' ' << b << std::endl;`, I find it prints `1 2` in both times rather than `2 1`, why will the compare function called twice with same order? For an array with 2 elemens, shouldn't it be enough to just compare once?

Comment: The function can be called a million times if the runtime library feels like doing so.  The goal is to see if your comparison function is bogus, and it is.  If you claim that "2" comes before "1", and at the same time "1" comes before "2", does that sound like something will go haywire?  See the [docs](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/stable_sort) about the comparison function and what a *strict-weak-order* means.

Comment: I forgot to say, in `std::sort` it will be called twice, but in `std::stable_sort` it will only be called once with output `1 2`

Comment: Also, is the real algorithm you're after `std::partition` or `std::stable_partition`?  If the first character is a digit, group that into some "digit" pile, and every other string gets grouped into a "non-digit" pile.  Is this the real goal?

Comment: Thanks a lot, but the docs does not give the idea about strict-weak-ordering, I find it in another [stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/979759/operator-and-strict-weak-ordering). So the problem is that iut does not judge 2 elements using `==`, but instead `!(a<b) && !(b<a)`, so it will be compared twice in sort (I have not looked into stable sort yet).

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Yes, it can be achieved using partition, but I'm trying to solve it using judge one compare function, and I encountered this problem which I skipped at that time. Now I revisit it.

Comment: So why are you using the wrong algorithm to do the job?  You see it is a partitioning problem, not a sorting problem.

Comment: Why is it not possible using sort? The idea is about order, if it has "larger" order it gets to the right half of the array. I think if we define correct order, we might be able to group it in the right half too. Am i misunderstanding it?

Comment: Yes, you are misunderstanding.  There is no "order" in what you are doing.  You are doing a "grouping".  An order means specifically `a < b`.  If you say both `a < b` and `b < a`, that is ambiguous, not an ordering.  If you want to keep the relative order within each group, that is what `std::stable_partition` is meant for.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Thanks for clarifying. Would you like to organize the discussion as an answer? Although Victor Istomin gives good answer, but I think the discussion makes thing clearer. If you are busy, I can later answer my own question while referencing the answer of both of you.

Comment: I think you should answer your own question.  It looks like you wanted `partition` or similar, but I leave it to you to point out the misconception you had and the resolution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to answer my own question but many thanks to PaulMckenzie for his help in the discussion and Victor Istomin's answer.

It turns out that sort does not work in the way I thought it should be. It expects *strict-weak-order*, which means `a > b` and `b > a` **cannot** be true at the same time, otherwise the *behavior is undefined*. Also, its way to judge if 2 elements equal is using `!(a < b) && !(b > a)` because it only uses the `<` operator instead of `==` operator.

The mistake in my code is that I always return false in this case, so that the expression `!(a < b) && !(b > a)` will be true, and sort considers them to equal, thus not swapping them.

The right solution as PaulMckenzie points out, is using `stable_partiion` (or `partition` if relative order is not needed). The principle is to use sort only when we have clear rule of comparing elements, if we just want to group same elements together, `partition` is good.

It seems I had some false delusions about sort function, thanks for pointing out.

**----------------- update ----------------**

Caleth points out in the comment that the strict-weak-order is not enforced, but the behavior will be undefined if violated. Updated my description of that part. Thanks.

Comment: It isn't enforced. `std::sort` is documented as having *undefined behaviour* if the comparison *doesn't* implement a strict weak ordering on the data. That doesn't mean "the result might be incorrect", it means "your program is no longer bound by the rules of C++", which includes such possibilities as "appears to work, but trashes unrelated data"

Comment: @biggerfish Maybe you got confused by the word "sort".  In C++ and most other languages, "sort" has a specific meaning.  In laid-back English talk, "sort" could mean to group things.  But this isn't laid-back English, it is computer science.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Yes I think so. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like 'compare' works exactly as you wrote: returns false if first char of second string is digit.

By the way, this compare function won't work as expected (whatever you expect from it, I have no idea) in general case. In C++, sort comparator should implement strict weak ordering. In other words, there should be no case when 'a < b' and 'b < a' at the same time.