# What are the principles of the 'insert' function of set in C++ STL?

Tags: c++, stl, set

For this piece of code below：

```cpp
int main()
{
    std::set<Node> s;
    for (int i = 0; i <= 5; i++)
        s.insert(Node(i));
    s.insert(Node(4));
    for (auto itor = s.begin(); itor != s.end(); itor++)
    {
        std::cout << itor->val << ' ';
    }
}
```

When the sign '<' is overwrote as below, the output is: '5 4 3 2 1 0'

```cpp
struct Node
{
    int val;
    Node(int _val = -1) : val(_val) {}
    bool operator<(const Node &p) const
    {
        return val > p.val;
    }
};
```

When I change the function into this:

```cpp
bool operator<(const Node &p) const
{
    return val >= p.val;
}
```

The output changes into: '5 4 4 3 2 1 0'.
The difference confuses me, could someone explain why this happened and explain the principles of the 'insert' function?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with `insert`, but by using `>=` you break the premise of "strict weak ordering". https://stackoverflow.com/questions/979759/operator-and-strict-weak-ordering/981299#981299

Comment: https://duckduckgo.com/?q=strict+weak+ordering+c%2B%2B&t=fpas&ia=about

Comment: `val > p.val` not `val >= p.val`. 'Less than' should never return true for two equal elements.

Answer (score 5):

`std::set` uses `operator<` on the key type by default, so in the first case, it uses the `operator<` defined for `Node` to compare the keys, which in turn uses `>` to compare the underlying integers, so you see a descending sequence of integers.

`std::set` expects that the order provided is a *strict weak order* as a precondition.  In the second case, your `operator<` is not a strict weak order, thus you violate the precondition, triggering undefined behavior.  Therefore, the implementation is confused.  (Undefined behavior means anything can happen — the program can produce strange results, crash, put your computer on fire, produce nasal demons, etc.)

Answer (score 5):

Custom comparison functions in STL containers must meet the requirements, i.e. they must induce a *strict weak ordering relation*. The second operator overload with `val >= p.val` fails to do exactly that, and the behavior is thus undefined.

From [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set) on std::set:

> Everywhere the standard library uses the Compare requirements, uniqueness is determined by using the equivalence relation. In imprecise terms, two objects a and b are considered equivalent if neither compares less than the other: `!comp(a, b) && !comp(b, a)`.

Comment: Thanks for your answering, I have figured it out.