# Why does inbuilt sort function for c++ does not function when we use equals '=' sign in comparator function?

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting

C++ inbuilt sort function does not work when we use equals sign in its comparator function with large and repeating input. I have pasted the code here and in validate section if I use equals sign in (val1<=val2) so this does not work for large and repeating inputsbut if i use it without equals sign everything works fine. Can anyone explain why?

I have already tried the code in different compilers as well as different devices.The same problem persists there as well.

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
bool validate(int val1,int val2)
{
    if(val1<=val2)  
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
int main()
{
    int total_elements;
    cin>>total_elements;
    vector<int> nums(total_elements);

    for(int i=0;i<total_elements;i++)
      cin>>nums[i];

    sort(nums.begin(),nums.end(),validate);

    for(int i=0;i<total_elements;i++)
      cout<<nums[i]<<" ";


}
```

Runtime error occurs and the processing stops in the middle but if i use it without equals sign everything works fine.

Comment: It is a requirement of the algorithm.

Comment: Look for "strict weak ordering" on the web. That's what you need for `std::sort` to work.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/979759/operator-and-strict-weak-ordering

Comment: The `validate` must satisfy that `validate(a,a)==false`.

Comment: Unrelated: Be cautious with `#include<bits/stdc++.h>` ([Why](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h)) and `using namespace std;` ([Why](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)). Be very careful when combining the two as they amplify each other's worst effects. If you are doing this for speed during competitions, note that `#include<bits/stdc++.h>` slows your build times by close to an order of magnitude. After two or three compiles, the time saved on typing is usually eaten up.

Comment: `if(val1<=val2)  
        return true;
    else
        return false;` can be written better/simpler as just `return val1 <= val2;`.

Comment: `#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;` - Please, don't *ever* do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the ≤ relation  is not a strict weak ordering.

Strict weak ordering is is [defined](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_ordering#Strict_weak_orderings) by:

> A strict weak ordering is a binary relation < on a set S that is a strict partial order (a transitive relation that is **irreflexive**, or equivalently,[6] that is asymmetric) in which the relation "neither a < b nor b < a" is transitive.

Note the requirement of [irreflexivity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflexive_relation#Related_terms).

> A binary relation is called irreflexive, or anti-reflexive, if it doesn't relate any element to itself.

It is easy to show that ≤ does not have this property. Consider for example: 0 ≤ 0. Clearly, this number (and also all other integers) is related with itself, so ≤ is not irreflexive (it is reflexive) and therefore is not a strict partial order and therefore it is not a strict weak ordering.

The comparison function of `std::sort` is required to be a strict weak ording. Using ≤ violates this requirement, and behaviour of using it is undefined.

Comment: Thank you sir , this explains everything.

Answer (score 3):

The algorithm requires the function to define a [strict weak ordering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_ordering#Strict_weak_orderings), otherwise its behaviour is undefined.

This means that,

- an element is not ordered before itself;
- if `x` is ordered before `y`, `y` is not ordered before `x`;
- if `x` is ordered before `y` and `y` is ordered before `z`, `x` is ordered before `z`.

(These are formally known as irreflexivity, asymmetry, and transitivity.)

Using `<=` violates both the first points, since

- `x <= x` for all `x`;
- if `x == y` then you have both `x <= y` and `y <= x`.

Comment: Thank you sir, now i get the concept for it.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a layman's explanation of why using `<=` isn't going to work.

I am the sort function that requires a `true` or `false` answer to determine if an item comes before the other.  I give you two items that happen to be equal, call them item A and item B.  I ask you "which comes before the other?"  You say "A", because `a <= b` (you return `true`).

Then I take the same two equal items, but give them to you first B, then A.  You now tell me that "B" comes before A because again, `a <= b`.  Huh?  That's ambiguous.  You first told me one thing, that A comes before B, and then contradicted yourself by telling me that "B comes before A", and all I did was hand you the same two items, just in a different order.

That's why using `<=` isn't going to work -- it goes completely wild if the two items are equal.

BTW, the Visual C++ debug runtime does this very same test I described, to determine if your sort criteria follows a strict-weak-order.  If VC++ detects this ambiguity, an assertion is raised and you get that scary dialog that you have invalid comparison criteria.

Answer (score 1):

The way the comparator determines if two elements are equal is if neither one is less then the other. In other words, if we have `a` and `b`, then if `a < b` and `b < a` are both false the values are considered equal.

For simplicity, let's assume we have `int`s. If the comparator uses `<=` and `a = b = 4`, then `a <= b` and `b <= a` are both true.

You can read more details on the requirements on [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Compare).

Answer (score 0):

Sort requires [strict weak ordering](https://isocpp.org/blog/2016/05/strict-weak-ordering-and-stl) to work:

> Almost all stl containers rely on strict weak ordering. A
>   strict weak ordering defines the relative position of elements in
>   terms of precedence of one item over other. For eg. if you have a room
>   full of person and you have to form a queue based on their height, a
>   person with "lesser" height will "precede" the person with greater
>   height. For a function to be satisfying strict weak ordering following
>   conditions need to be met:
>
> ```
> a < b => !(b < a) 
> !(a < b) && !(b < a) => a≡b
> ```