# How does std::map know when two keys are equal when using a custom comparator?

Tags: c++

```
struct StrCmp {
   bool operator()(char const *a, char const *b) const
   {
      return std::strcmp(a, b) < 0;
   }
};
    
// StrCmp specified in map declaration
map<const char *, int, StrCmp> strMap;
char p[] = "Test";
strMap[p] = 5;
cout << strMap["Test"];
```

In the code above the output is `5`... How does the map know that the strings are equal ? The comparator only gives information that the `strcmp` value is greater.

Comment: `if (!comp(a,b) && !comp(b,a)) { /* Equal */}`

Comment: When neither value is greater (or less) than the other, the `std::map` can assume that they are eqivalent.

Comment: And this is why your comparator must provide [strict weak ordering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/979759/operator-and-strict-weak-ordering).  If it doesn't, `std::map` will get confused.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per the [std::map](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map) documentation on cppreference.com:

> `std::map` is a sorted associative container that contains key-value pairs with **unique keys**. Keys are sorted by using the comparison function `Compare`. Search, removal, and insertion operations have logarithmic complexity. Maps are usually implemented as red-black trees.
>
> Everywhere the standard library uses the [*Compare*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Compare) requirements, **uniqueness is determined by using the equivalence relation**. In imprecise terms, two objects `a` and `b` are considered equivalent (not unique) if neither compares less than the other: `!comp(a, b) && !comp(b, a)`.