# map with struct as key works incorrectly

Tags: c++, dictionary

I'm trying to use user-defined struct as a key in std::map. In order to do that, I define comparison operator inside the struct. Then I add two instances of the class into map.

```
#include <map>
#include <iostream>

struct Fraction {
    int num, den; // numerator and denumenator

    explicit Fraction() : num(1), den(1) {}
    explicit Fraction(int num_, int den_) : num(num_), den(den_) {}

    bool operator<(const Fraction& rhs) const {
        return num * rhs.den < den * rhs.num;
    }

};

int main() {
    std::map<Fraction, int> mymap;
    
    mymap[Fraction(100, 100)] = 1;
    mymap[Fraction(200, 200)] = 2;
    
    std::cout << mymap.at(Fraction(100, 100)) << std::endl;
    std::cout << mymap.at(Fraction(200, 200)) << std::endl;
}
```

I expect to get

```
1
2
```

but the result is

```
2
2
```

Why?

Comment: [Operator< and strict weak ordering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/979759/operator-and-strict-weak-ordering)

Comment: In order to precise the very relevant @Jason comment:  both ```Fraction``` represent the same value as it is enforced by the ```operator <```

Comment: `100/100` and `200/200` are the same fraction, so the behavior looks correct to me?

Comment: Thanks everyone for answering the question. I added additional check in operator< in order to distinguish the two cases (which I need).

Comment: I'd recommend passing an object for comparison instead of just modifying the `<` operator. Given `Fraction f1(1, 1); Fraction f2(2, 2);` you'd expect both `f1 < f2` and `f2 < f1` to yield false; the only scenario where you don't want this is when using this for the map, so use a custom type like `struct MapFractionLess { constexpr bool operator()(Fraction const& f1, Fraction const& f2) const { auto p1 = f1.num * f2.den; auto p2 = f1.den * f2.num;  return (p1 == p2) ? (f1.den < f2.den) : (p1 < p2); }  }; std::map<Fraction, int, MapFractionLess> ...`

Comment: @user43283 *"added additional check"* Can you show the resulting operator?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat updated
```
inline bool operator<(const Fraction& rhs) const {
 if (num * rhs.den == den * rhs.num) {
  return std::tie(num, den) < std::tie(rhs.num, rhs.den);
 }
 return (num * rhs.den < den * rhs.num);
}
```

Comment: @user43283 Please don't modify the question so that the answers you've gotten doesn't make sense. It's enough if you show that updated `operator<` here in the comments. Also note that I added a comment about updating `operator<` to my answer.

Comment: Aha, so you not only want to distinguish those two fractions, but also to maintain a certain sort order (by the fraction values)?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat yes

Comment: I see. That should've been mentioned in the question. Because otherwise I was confused why you'd use this kind of comparator.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A `map` considers two *Keys* equal if neither `a < b` nor `b < a` is true.

```cpp
mymap[Fraction(100, 100)] = 1;
mymap[Fraction(200, 200)] = 2;
```

The first fraction is `100/100` and the second is `200/200` and neither `100/100 < 200/200` nor `200/200 < 100/100` is true mathematically. You are not using integer division to do the comparison though, so lets check `num * rhs.den < den * rhs.num;` or `100*200 < 200*100` and the same applies there.

- Neither `100*200 < 200*100` nor `200*100 < 100*200` is true - so they are considered equal.

This is why you in `mymap[Fraction(200, 200)] = 2;` overwrite the value stored by `mymap[Fraction(100, 100)] = 1;` and there is only one *Key* fraction in your map.

---

I noted that you said *"I added additional check in `operator<` in order to distinguish the two cases"* in the comments. This is probably a mistake since it will break the expectations users of your `Fraction` class will have. Consider this snippet:

```cpp
Fraction a(100, 100);
Fraction b(200, 200);

if(a < b) {
    // should not happen
} else if(b < a) {
    // should not happen
} else {
    // the expected
}
```

If you've modified `operator<` to be able to use both `a` and `b` as *Keys* in your `map`, then one of the two *"should not happen"* cases will kick in.

Alternatives:

- Use a `std::multimap` where multiple *Keys* considered equal can be stored. This will however change your mapping so that multiple `100/100` *Keys* can be stored, not only both `100/100` and `200/200`.
- Use a `std::map` with a custom comparator:

  ```
  struct FractionCmp {
      bool operator()(const Fraction& lhs, const Fraction& rhs) const {
          if(lhs < rhs) return true;
          if(rhs < lhs) return false;
          // they are really equivalent, but:
          return lhs.num < rhs.num;
      }
  };

  std::map<Fraction, int, FractionCmp> mymap;
  ```